# how i connect my arduino to my own web site?

Tags: web, arduino

i have a question about my arduino,
first i have an arduino which reading a sensor and i have my own website , let's say it's name is 
www.my-project.net , now i want to put that reading of the sensor on the site so every one else can open the site and see the reading.
the problem is i don't know how to make the arduino sends data to the website , i mean how to make a code where i put my username and password of the site and make the arduino sends the data.
any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should POST the data with the Ethernet/WebClient:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebClient
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=145277.0

What do you mean by username and password? Where do you want to enter the credentials? Should the Arduino authenticate itself or the visitor?

Comment: sorry if i dont understand what you mean because i just bought the site yesterday and i dont know too much about servers.. etc.
but what i mean when i bought the site i got a username and password which i use them to put anything i want on the site , now i wont to make the arduino do this .

Answer (score 0):

You should use an intermediary service such as [Xively](https://xively.com/). You can use premade libraries on the [Arduino](https://github.com/xively/xively_arduino) that make it easy to talk to Xively or another webservice. Once the data has been stored in Xively you can use the [REST API](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/) to get data onto your website.

This is the easiest way in my opinion to get your devices data on the internet.

Comment: how about mysql , can i use it ?? and if so , from where should i begin ??

Comment: Xively will store your data in time series database. If you want to use a mysql database on your website you can use that to augment that data that is stored in Xively.